# Sütterlin Help?

Tags: handwriting, comparison

Can anyone figure out the hand written words? This is a paper label from an old German made hat.

The handwritten words are after "Qualität / Quality" and "Farbe / Color". The company that made this hat (Wegener) like to use names of towns or places for their colors.

[image]

Comment: The hand written words are after "Qualität / Quality" and "Farbe / Color".

Comment: The company that made this hat (Wegener) like to use names of towns or places for their colors.

Comment: Was konntest Du denn selbst bislang entziffern? Hast Du eine Tabelle gefunden, in der Schreibschriftsütterlinbuchstaben aufgelistet sind, und konntest Du einige der unklaren Buchstaben eingrenzen?

Comment: So oft wie wir Sütterlinanfragen in der Vergangenheit hatten und es jedes mal beantwortet wurde bin ich mir nicht sicher, in wiefern das offtopic ist.

Comment: Is this the manufacturer: http://www.wegener.org/ueber-wegener.html ? If yes, you might be successful asking them. "Lunze" als Qualität scheint falsch/ kein echter Begriff zu sein.

Comment: Here is your good friend for Sütterlin:  http://www.suetterlinschrift.de/Lese/Sutterlin0.htm

Comment: Hello Shegit,  Looks like it could be "Lunze" for Qualität. Highly possible it's a made up word.  I will have to check some other hats.  Unfortunately Wegener has lost such information. Do you have any idea about the Farbe?   Also thank to everyone else.  This is my website. I have a very large collection.  https://germanaustrianhats.invisionzone.com/

Comment: It does not look like Sütterlin. For example the "e" is definitely not.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no definite answer because it could be specialist jargon of textile industry from former times or even the individual jargon of the manufactory.

Qualität:  Could be "Lunze", perhaps also "Lanze". The latter could be a variant of "Lancé", see http://www.stofflexikon.com/lance/662/lance.html.

Answer (score 1):

## Lunze spune mel

#### = animal’s lungs’ quality colored with a spoon of honey

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lunze
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spune#Middle_English
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mel#Breton

Comment: Doesn't sound plausible.